# Как достать данные с помощью JSOUP

Tags: android, jsoup

Есть такая структура

```
<div class="b-player-skin__header-inner">
<span>007: СПЕКТР</span>
<div class="b-player-skin__header-origin">Spectre</div></div></div>
<div class="b-player-skin-left">
<div class="b-player-skin__poster-wrap">
<a class="b-player-skin__poster-image" indx="0" rel="#b-screenshots-gallery" href="#">
<img src="http://img.dotua.org/fsua_items/cover/00/38/41/1/00384173.jpg" ></a></div></div></div>
```

Необходимо достать данные о фильме, рус.название, анг и ссылку на изображение.
Можно ли доставать текст с определенно класса в определенном теге? Просто в теге `div`, например, не только эти название.

Мой код `titleRus = doc.select("div").select("span").text();` достает как раз таки всё. Существует ли что-то, типа такого `titleRus = doc.select("div" из class="b-player-skin__header-inner" ).select("span").text();`

То есть в теге `div` есть `class="b-player-skin__header-inner"` и из вложенного тега `span` необходимо достать данные.

Может не совсем корректно задал вопрос, но суть я думаю уловить можно.
Заранее благодарю и с НАСТУПАЮЩИМИ!!!)))

Comment: doc.getElementsByClass("b-player-skin__header-inner").text() Как-нибудь так попробуйте. Ну или под дебагом в эту сторону копайте. С наступающим)

Answer (score 1):

> Можно ли доставать текст с определенно класса в определенном теге

Если я правильно вас понял, то вы можете поступить примерно так:

```
ArrayList<String> foundText = new ArrayList<>();
Elements els = doc.getElementsByTag("НУЖНЫЙ_ТЭГ_НАПРИМЕР_DIV");
for(Element el : els)
{
    Element elWithClass = el.getElementsByClass("НУЖНЫЙ_КЛАСС").first();
    if(elWithClass != null)
    {
        foundText.add(elWithClass.text());
    }
}
```

Также вам могут быть полезны методы типа

`getElementsByAttributeValue(String key, String value)`

Comment: после `getElementsByTag` невозможно вызвать `getElementsByClass` - ошибка компиляции

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександров, да, действительно. Это методы `Element`, а не `Elements`. Тогда всё несколько сложнее - см. обновлённый ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup понимает [селекторы CSS](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html), поэтому можно прямо в запросе писать, что вам надо:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse( html );

// взять все узлы span входящие непосредственно в div с классом b-player...
// и получить из них скопом текст (т.к. нужный нам span - единственный)
String name = doc.select( "div.b-player-skin__header-inner > span" ).text();
System.out.println( "selector: " + name );

// можно выбрать нужный узел, и разбираться в нем руками:
// взять все div с классом b-player..., из них взять первый элемент
Element div = doc.select( "div.b-player-skin__header-inner" ).get( 0 );
// для каждого подузла вывести
for ( Element e : div.children() ) {
    System.out.println( ">>> " + e );
}
```

Comment: Первый вариант `String name = doc.select( "div.b-player-skin__header-inner > span" ).text();
System.out.println( "selector: " + name );` выдал пустую строку, а на втором, под дебагом, `Element div = doc.select( "div.b-player-skin__header-inner" ).get( 0 );
// для каждого подузла вывести
for ( Element e : div.children() ) {
    System.out.println( ">>> " + e );
}` приложение вылетело((

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить пустой класс именно для span'a(Просто имя класса без стилей).
Вроде: `<span class="nujnoe_mne">123</span>`.

И парсить уже по данному классу:

```
titleRus = doc.select(".nujnoe_mne");
```

Таким образом он будет парсить только те спаны, где будет указан данный класс.